# Android: start an Activity from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I want to start an activity from a BroadcastReceiver. The issue is that, when I try to launch it, i get an exception which tells me to add the "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" flag, because my Receiver is registered into a Service and not into an Activity.
So, I modified my code into the BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
    Intent start=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(start);
}
```

But my Activity does not start. Does anyone can explain me why I get this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's just a typo.

You have to call `start.addFlags()`, not `intent.addFlags()`.

Comment: @user1071138 if this solve your problem, why don't you accept this as the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with flags,it is used like this

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

but you have used `addFlags()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :-

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


   intent.setClass(context, nextgoingactivity);
    intent.putExtra("sipcallid", sipAddress); // your data
 intent.putExtra("sipAddress", sipcallid);  // your data
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent); 

}
```

and update your AndroidManifesh.xml,

```
 <receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" android:label="Call Receiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".nextgoingactivity"/>
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
```

It should solve your query!